# Accessing data from inside html code to the main suitelet code

Tags: netsuite

I have written an html code inside a suitelet and Within the script tags of this html I am calling data from another platform through an api call

Data is stored in a json format in a variable object called info.

How do I retrieve this 'info' value from inside the html code to the outside main suitelet code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the information you want in an HTML tag then you put a code on your suitelet that will get all the parameter and you should be able to get that information:

```
funcntion suitelet(response, request){

     if(request.getMethod() == 'GET') {
     ///render html whith textbox tag and with id=yourparamatername 
     }
     else if(request.getMethod() == 'POST') {
        var data = request.getParameter('yourparamatername');
     }
}
```